# How to write system-time and date to a text-log with Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, date, time

I'd like to create a .js script that will write the current system-time and date to a running .txt file log, so I can then view those various times and dates in the future.

This would mean if I ran the .js file, it would "ammend and add" to the existing list of times and dates, rather than over-writing anything.

Many thanks for any help,

Martin

Comment: In what context are you talking?  Javascript in a webpage?  A trusted Javascript plugin?  Server-side Javascript?  Something else?

Comment: Usually `.js` is a JavaScript file, but you tag your post with `Java`, which is a completely different technology than `JavaScript`.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Ah, apologies, I do mean a .js script. I'll try to change the tag on the question, cheers.

Comment: Are you working with something like node.js on the server side?

Comment: ooh, I've absolutely no idea at all. I'd just like to create a log.txt file that was added to every time a particular .js file was executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Javascript can't do it, since it only runs on the client side and even there it would have no access to any storage other than Cookies or HTML5 Offline Storage.

You would need to combine it with something on the server side, for instance use a resource loader, such as [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) and fire an event using the callback provided that would write the log via a server-side language.